# How to resize the image size on browser using Laravel 5.2?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 in my project. But now I am facing one problem in my project is image fetch on page. In my project showing images on my home page but images size is more than 2mb and it take time showing images. So some one suggest to use grunt for image resize. And I don't know what is grunt and how to use? I tried to find what is grunt not getting proper solutions. Please suggest me.

Comment: Grunt is a task automation tool. There's a package for Grunt called [imagemin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin) and will, based on the settings you provide, optimize images for you. Also here's [Grunt's official site](http://gruntjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io) with Laravel. Start with [this tutorial](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-image-upload-and-resize-example-using-intervention-image-packageexample.html) to get the idea about how to upload and resize images. This code from the tutorial could be helpful:

```
$image = $request->file('image');
    $input['imagename'] = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

$destinationPath = public_path('/thumbnail');
$img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
$img->resize(100, 100, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
})->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input['imagename']);

$destinationPath = public_path('/images');
$image->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but is there any way to on browser we can resize the image size

Comment: You can resize image in browser by setting it's width, but it will not affect on loading speed. Usually you want to resize/optimize uploaded images.

Comment: can I use Laravel Elixir